# Why does does JRE download size vary so much?

Tags: java

The file sizes for JRE downloads on the [download page for jre-6u31](http://www.java.com/de/download/manual.jsp)
 vary greatly between platforms.
Since they provide essentially the same functionality, I would have
expected that they are roughly the same size.
Why are they so different?

```
Windows          16.1 MB 
Solaris (32-Bit) 25.2 MB 
Solaris (64-Bit) 11.2 MB + 25.2 MB 32-bit Solaris 
Solaris x86      20.3 MB
Solaris x64       7.5 MB
Linux RPM        20.2 MB
Linux            20.7 MB
Linux x64        20.3 MB 
Linux x64 RPM    19.7 MB
```

Comment: interesting question though I wonder if it has anything to do with programming at all...

Answer (score 4):

I would say they are roughtly the same.  What varies is the amount of libraries which come with the platform and which need to be added. e.g. can the JRE use a LZM library which comes with the OS or does it need to provide its own. (Just an example).

Answer (score 3):

Because JRE not uses jvm, JRE source code differs according platform.

Comment: The JRE doesn't include the source. If you download the source, it includes all the source for all platforms.